# Line animation with constant length along rounded rectangle swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation

please, how to do infinity line animation along path (rounded rectangle) without stopping, the line have to have constant/same length in each time - see attached [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQWbM.png)
I found out only this solution, but this isn't what I want.

--- for path:

```
path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100), byRoundingCorners:.allCorners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width:16, height:16))
```

--- animations:

```
let strokeEndAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.duration = 10
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.duration = 12
        group.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
        group.animations = [animation]
        return group
    }()

    let strokeStartAnimation: CAAnimation = {
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeStart")
        animation.beginTime = 2
        animation.fromValue = 0
        animation.toValue = 1
        animation.duration = 10
        animation.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)

        let group = CAAnimationGroup()
        group.duration = 12
        group.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT
        group.animations = [animation]
        return group
    }()
```

Thank You

Comment: I can't make any sense out of your description.

Comment: @DuncanC; I tried to solve the issue OP is having and failed lol.. I came up with: https://pastebin.com/QPLYvzMf so far.. if you paste that `viewDidLoad` into a `UIViewController` you'll see the old 90's `snake` animation along a path but right before repeating, the snake disappears for a split second and starts over again.. That is the part they are having a problem with.. They can't get it to repeat smoothly because `CAShapeLayer`'s `endStroke` is clamped at 1.0.

Comment: @martinzly; This is the closest I could get: https://pastebin.com/sH8PTG45 I used masking.. the only issue would be the length of the line growing due to the type of mask I used..

Comment: @Brandon thank You for answer, yes, this is what I need, but without start/stop. I have to use something else instead of layer animation or is here some solution?